# What is the proper way of acknowledging SQS message in Akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Let say I have a constant stream of SQS message from AWS. I have a flow which take messages and perform some side effects that is possibly unsafe.

I want to ACK all the messages, if the process failed for any reason I want to push the message to another queue. If the process succeded I want to delete it. I don't want to have not ACK messages.

Also I want to be able to dispatch the incoming messages into parallelized workers.

What is the proper way of doing such a thing ?

I devised that this is working but I wonder if it is a "good" solution:

```scala
  val flow = Flow[String]
    .map { value =>
      if (value == "global")
        throw new Exception("Unexpected failure parsing global")
      println(value)
    }

  val result = Source(
    Seq("coucou", "baba", "global", "obvious", "test", "lol", "supercool")
  )
    .mapAsync(2) { el =>
      Source
        .single(el)
        .via(flow)
        .recover {
          case ex: Throwable =>
            println(s"SEND message ${el} to another queue")
        }
        .runWith(Sink.foreach { _ =>
          println(s"DELETE message ${el}")
        })
    }
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

What do you think?

Comment: Why do you create a Source from a single elment?. You could use the Graph DSL to create another flow and use the Partition to redirects the errors to another queue

Comment: Because I want the ACK to happen strictly after the end of the inner flow. But maybe it will happen after the end of the flow with Graph DSL, do you have any example of this?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 also I want to have the message in my recover. Actually I'm looking for a `recover` method which gives me the value that made the flow fail.

Answer (score 0):

In `flow`, instead of performing side effects, maybe you can simply wrap it in an `Either` so that you can handle left and right differently with `nok` and `ok`.

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.SinkShape
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, GraphDSL, Partition, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object PartitionStream {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("PartitionStream")
    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

    val flow = Flow[String].map { value =>
      if (value == "global")
        Left(MyException("Unexpected failure parsing global"))
      else Right(value)
    }

    val sink = Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val partition = b.add(
        Partition[Either[MyException, String]](2, el => if (el.isLeft) 0 else 1)
      )
      val collectNok = Flow[Either[MyException, String]].collect {
        case Left(ex) => ex
      }
      val collectOk = Flow[Either[MyException, String]].collect {
        case Right(value) => value
      }
      val nok = b.add(Sink.foreach[MyException](x => println(x.msg)))
      val ok = b.add(Sink.foreach[String](println))
      partition.out(0) ~> collectNok ~> nok
      partition.out(1) ~> collectOk ~> ok
      SinkShape(partition.in)
    })

    Source(
      List("coucou", "baba", "global", "obvious", "test", "lol", "supercool")
    ).via(flow).runWith(sink)
  }

  case class MyException(msg: String)
}
```